# .htaccess This webpage has a redirect loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, password-protection

I think I messed up.

I am currently in the stages of learning .htaccess for, of course, Apache.

I have applied a Password Protection to a directory on my website.
I also have different directories that hold different information, that are not protected.

For example:

http://www.example.com/forum/ = Not Protected
http://www.example.com/construction/ = Protected

Now I do know that an .htaccess file can apply to an entire website if placed in the root, or you can have a .htaccess file applied to a specific directory.

In the root of...

http://www.example.com/

I used to have a .htaccess file with a 301 Redirect (In The Root Folder) that would translate all requests of example.com and or http://example.com into http://www.example.com. I removed that 301 Redirect completely.

But, for some reason, I am still getting this error message in which I cannot access the...
http://www.example.com/forum/ directory.

I have completed all of the following steps to troubleshoot the problem...
1. Cleared Cache/Cookies/Sessions - Completely
2. Flushed the DNS via my Operating System
3. Restarted my computer
4. Have a DNS Service in which provides me the latest DNS Information.

What I am asking is A. How do I remove this message? And B. How do I still translate example.com requests into www.example.com requests without having this problem occur?

Thank you!
Let me know,
I appreciate the offer that I will receive,
Aaron

Comment: Please provide the contents of both .htaccess files. And it most likely doesn't have anything to do with DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your root folder you can still place a .htaccess with the following rule to redirect from example.com to www.example.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

In your password protected folder place a .htaccess like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected folder /construction/"
AuthUserFile /absolute/path/to/your/public/www/folder/construction/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

also place a [.htpasswd](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) in there.

A redirect loop only occurs when a requests always matches your redirect condition. Maybe you had a wrong .htaccess in the root folder or there were other rules in there you didn't mention?